# Read a large number of emails using Gmail API

Tags: java, email, google-api-java-client, gmail-api

I am trying to parse contents of a large number of emails in a gmail account. My code works fine on the Google App Engine for upto ~4000 emails, but I get the following error when the number is higher

```
Uncaught exception from servlet com.google.apphosting.runtime.HardDeadlineExceededError
```

My sample space has about 4500 emails and the code below will take a little over a minute to get all the emails. I am looking to lower the execution time to fetch the emails.

My code is:

```
final List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
BatchRequest batchRequest = gmail.batch();

JsonBatchCallback<Message> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<Message>() {
    public void onSuccess(Message message, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
        synchronized (messages) {
            messages.add(message);  
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders)
            throws IOException {
    }
};

int batchCount=0;
if(noOfEmails>0){
    for(Message message : messageList){
        gmail.users().messages().get("me", message.getId()).set("format", "metadata").set("fields", "payload").queue(batchRequest, callback);
        batchCount++;
        if(batchCount==1000){
            try{
                noOfEmailsRead+=batchCount;
                log.info("No of Emails Read : " + noOfEmailsRead);
                batchRequest.execute();
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
            batchCount=0;
        }
    }
    noOfEmailsRead+=batchCount;
    log.info("No of Emails Read : " + noOfEmailsRead);
    batchRequest.execute();
}
```

Comment: A DeadlineExceeded error usually indicates that Google's servers aren't responding to your scripts quickly enough. Improving the performance of your code is unlikely to help much, but even if it did, what happens when 4500 becomes 5500, or 6500? You may need to adopt a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291910/google-app-engine-harddeadlineexceedederror): RuntimeError

> HardDeadlineExceededError

is because you must finish your task in 30 seconds.

---

To accomplish this whole task in about 30 seconds, you can use the [Divide and Conquer Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms). This technique breaks the task into smaller tasks, using all the parallel power of your processor. To determine the best number of tasks, can be little hard because depends on your OS, Processor, .... You must do some tests and benchmark.

Java have the [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) that can help you to accomplish this issue. You can use the [Fork/Join Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html).

Answer (score 0):

you will need to break up the work into smaller tasks that can each complete in under 30 seconds.

A simple google search would have revealed this to you.